# Find the derivative of $\frac{(2x−1)e^{−2x}}{(1−x)^2}$

Tags: derivatives

I need to find the derivative of $$\frac{(2x−1)e^{−2x}}{(1−x)^2}$$

I seems very complex to me so I'm wondering if there is a rule or formula I should be using? I attempted it using the chain rule first for the numerator (since I have $ ( 2 x- 1)$ multiplied by $e^{- 2 x}$ as my numerator) and then my plan was to use this rule: $(\frac{u}{v})′=\frac{vu′-uv′}{v^2}$.

It gets messy and complicated. Could someone please explain how you'd attempt this problem?

Comment: write the question properly

Comment: @Sanath You lost the division!

Comment: $(uvw)' = u'vw + uv'w+wvw'$

Comment: @amWhy Sorry - I changed it.

Comment: I did write it properly. Someone ruined it. How do I stop people changing it?

Comment: Hopefully people will let it alone: there's no mistaking the fraction, now!

Comment: Thanks amWhy. That's how the question is supposed to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to differentiate the product of $3$ functions, the product rule is still available:

$$
(fgh)' = ((fg)h)' = (fg)'h + (fg)h' = (f'g + fg')h + fgh' = f'gh + fg'h + fgh'
$$

(and if you had decided to group (gh) or (fh) at the outset, you can check you'll still get the same outcome)

So, if you take $f = 2x -1 $, $g = e^{-2x}$ and $h = (1-x)^{-2}$, you're set (notice I changed the exponent on $h$ to make this a product rule; you could similarly formulate things in terms of the quotient rule if you prefer)

Comment: It's a quotient, not a product. Someone kept undoing the fraction that was originally posted. Of course, one could write the given quotient as a product, as well!

Comment: hah, ok. I have edited my answer to account for this.

Comment: Thanks BaronVT and amWhy. That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{(2x−1)e^{−2x}}{(1−x)^2}=\frac{(1-x)^2\frac{d}{dx}[(2x−1)e^{−2x}]-(2x−1)e^{−2x}\frac{d}{dx}{(1−x)^2}}{(1-x)^4}
$$
I hope now you can solve easily

Comment: I think you have an error in the second term of the numerator of your fraction; you should be differentiating $(1-x)^2$ for that term.

Answer (score -2):

$$ \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f\left(x\right) =
\dfrac{-2{\cdot}\left(2x-1\right){\cdot}{\mathrm{e}}^{-\left(2x\right)}}{{\left(1-x\right)}^{2}}+\dfrac{2{\cdot}\left(2x-1\right){\cdot}{\mathrm{e}}^{-\left(2x\right)}}{{\left(1-x\right)}^{3}}+\dfrac{2{\mathrm{e}}^{-\left(2x\right)}}{{\left(1-x\right)}^{2}}
$$